# How to configure pull timeout on GCP PubSubTemplate?

Tags: spring, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

From the documentation on [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull) it says:

> Otherwise, the system may wait (for a bounded amount of time) until at least one message is available, rather than returning no messages.

Is there any way of configuring this "(for a bounded amount of time)"? I am using [`spring-cloud-gcp`](https://googleapis.dev/java/spring-cloud-gcp/3.3.0/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the document [`returnImmediately`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull#request-body) is deprecated.
However you can set the timeout to any `Asynchronous Pull` by mentioning the timeout value in [StreamingPullFuture#result](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/pubsub/latest/google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.futures.StreamingPullFuture#google_cloud_pubsub_v1_subscriber_futures_StreamingPullFuture_result). If you don't set `timeout` then the `result()` will block indefinitely, unless an exception is encountered first.

You can go through the [Pub/Sub Receiving messages Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-client-library#receive_messages) to understand better. You can also check this documentation regarding [the different types of pull subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull).

Comment: For my lib there are no pullAsync with a timeout: https://googleapis.dev/java/spring-cloud-gcp/3.3.0/index.html

Comment: I am unaware of how the `spring-cloud-gcp` library works. However you can achieve the same by using [Google's supported libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-client-library#receive_messages) itself. You should create a new thread with more detail and proper tags which will target the right audience for your question in this case that is `spring gcp cloud`. Because your problem is more related to `Spring` rather than `GCP`. Let me know if that is of any help .